# Interleave two unsorted arrays to get the lexicographically maximal result

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we have two unsorted arrays, A[1...m] and B[1...n]. The objective is to return an array C[1...(m+n)] formed by interleaving the elements from A and B (in other words, A[i] must precede A[i+1] and B[i] must precede B[i+1] in C) such that C is as large as possible in lexicographical order. What are some approaches to solve this problem in linear time?

The basic approach is greedy: if A[i] is bigger than B[j], then take A[i] and increment i, or else if B[j] is bigger than A[i] then take B[j] and increment j. The difficulty arises when A[i] and B[j] are equal. In this case we have to "look ahead" to find the first position k such that A[i+k] and B[j+k] differ. The code in C++ looks like this:

```
// A, B are the input vectors
vector<int> C;
auto it1 = A.begin();
auto it2 = B.begin();
while (it1 != A.end() || it2 != B.end()) {
    if (std::lexicographical_compare(it1, A.end(), it2, B.end())) {
        C.push_back(*it2++);
    } else {
        C.push_back(*it1++);
    }
}
```

Because of the requirement to look ahead, this can take quadratic time.

One approach to do it in linear time is to concatenate the two arrays with a separator that is guaranteed to compare less with all elements of the original arrays, compute the suffix array of this combined array, and use that in order to easily look up which suffix is greater instead of doing a full scan in every iteration of the `while` loop.

- As suffix array construction is relatively complicated, I am interested in whether simpler approaches exist.
- In addition, a suffix array uses linear extra memory and I am wondering whether there is a solution that takes linear time and only uses constant extra memory. (By this I mean that the memory occupied by the output array C doesn't count toward the limit, but you are only allowed to append to C, and thereafter may not go back to read or write any previous elements of C.)

Comment: When you look ahead, can't you just scan indexes forward, decide which you're copying, then copy?  You should never need more than 2 extra indexes (where you were, where you would be if you jumped forward, in each array) and then the copying is linear once you make your choice.  That should be linear and constant overhead.

Comment: Could you do a linear scan and condense all repeated characters into a tuple of (val, repetitions)? If you do this you should only ever need a look ahead of 1.

Comment: @btilly I think you're saying that once you find the first mismatch, you copy everything from the current iterator up to the mismatch point of the chosen string into the output then advance the current iterator to the mismatch point, so you never have to look at those elements again. That algorithm, however, is not actually correct.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin That fails to account for repetitions with period greater than 1, for example A = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ..., 2] and B = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ..., 3]

Comment: Hmmm, interesting not sure. I want to say there should be something you can do with keeping a tally of the differences or something. Also consider other linear time list scanning algorithm for hints of what might work. You might also want to look at partial sorting and k-way merge (2-way in this case). It also might be useful to look for abnormal cases (what are the part(s) of the lists that are going to be the most problematic to interweave based on their indexes and value)

Comment: @Brian No.  I'm saying that you scan forward on both, then decide what to do based on what the mismatch is.  You might wind up advancing A.  You might wind up advancing B.  You might wind up advancing both then  proceeding.  But in all cases all that you need to do is know the common value, the last emitted index, the two new values, and the indexes where the new values can be found.

Comment: @btilly I'm not sure what you're saying we should do with this information. If you have a working algorithm, I'd greatly appreciate it if you could write up an answer with the details.

Comment: @Brian I am fairly sure that it can be extended to a full algorithm with some work, but at the moment I only have something that works in the "easy cases".  Do you want to see my partial thoughts?

Comment: @btilly I think there could be value in seeing your partial thoughts put into code. I do want to find a full solution, but any ideas are potentially helpful for achieving that goal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to describe the partial algorithm that I have in pseudocode.

First of all the trivial cases.

```
if (it1 == A.end()) {
    copy from it2 until end
}
else if (it2 == A.end()) {
    copy from it1 until end
}
else if (*it1 < *it2) {
    copy one value from it1
}
else if (*it2 < *it1) {
    copy one value from it2
}
else {
    // This is where it gets tricky
    scan_forward(A, B, C, it1, it2)
}
```

Now the idea of `scan_forward` is that we find a way to scan forward, then take a big giant block of values.  This should take very little overhead if done right.  But "if done right" is tricky and I haven't figured it all out yet.  Still the idea is this.

```
it1_scan = copy of it1
it2_scan = copy of it2
while true {
    if (it1_scan == A.end()) {
        if (it2_scan == A.end() or  *it1 < *it2_scan) {
            copy it1 over
            copy it2 over
        }
        else if (*it1 == *it2_scan)  {
            scan forward on it2_scan
            if you find the end first or it2_scan finds something larger than *it1 {
                copy it1 over
                copy it2 over
            }
            else {
                copy it2 over until it2_scan's lower
                return and proceed
            }
        else {
            copy it2 until it2_scan
            return and proceed.
        }
    else if (it2_scan == B.end()) {
        Mirror logic for it2_scan knowing that it1_scan is not (yet) end.
    }
    else if (*it1_scan < *it2_scan) {
        copy it1 until it1_scan
        return and proceed.
    }
    else if (*it2_scan < *it1_scan) {
        copy it2 until it2_scan
        return and proceed.
    }
    else if (*it1 < *it1_scan) {
        copy it1 until it1_scan
        copy it2 until it2_scan
        return and proceed.
    }
    else {
       This is what I have not worked out.
       We want to do one of:
          - drain it1 and keep going
          - drain it2 and keep going
          - drain it1 then it2 then decide what to do.
    }
```

}

I began writing that complicated bit out and found that I have 3 courses to follow in parallel.  And a lot of options.  I did not work that out in detail, but it does seem that options do not multiply.  However you do get into a weird state where you know you want to do some of one, then backtrack and do some of the other.  But you have not yet decided which to copy first.  That piece of logic can go on surprisingly long, but I think only with bounded overhead.

However I confess to not working that part out in any detail.